# Referencing Workbook and Worksheet by Variables

Tags: variables, excel, vba

What is the proper syntax for referencing a different workbook's worksheet? The following code is throwing an error on the last line. Thanks!

```
'Instantiate Workbook variables
 Dim mWB As Workbook 'master workbook

'Instantiate Worksheet variables
 Dim mWS As Worksheet 'master worksheet

'Open Workbook, set variables and reference range
 Workbooks.Open ("Local 500GB HD:Users:user:Public:file.xlsx")
 Set mWB = ActiveWorkbook
 Set mWS = Sheets("Invoices")
 mWB.mWS.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Import Date" ' <---- This is the where the error is
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
Set mWS = Sheets("Invoices")
```

To

```
Set mWS = mWb.Sheets("Invoices")
```

Then just write `mWS.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Import Date"` on the last line.

In effect, you could just change the last line to read like I placed above, since your `ActiveWorkbook` is not changing, however, it's a best practice to qualify all your variables exactly, so unexpected behavior doesn't occur.