# reference different workbooks worksheets using object variables The workbook is already open

Tags: excel, vba, variables, object

I'm pounding my head against the wall with this. I've been writing the full workbooks().sheets() references. Looking for a shorter way to do it I found some stackoverflow posts and answers that seem so simple but when I try it... it doesn't work.
I don't need to open the workbook I want to reference since I found a way to code it to open automatically when the main workbook opens... and save and close when the main closes. 
I get a "Compile error: sub or function not defined" at the Set wb = Workbooks() line.

I followed as closely the answer to this question [Referencing Workbook and Worksheet by Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146558/referencing-workbook-and-worksheet-by-variables)

Is there a special place to define an object variable or may it be done in any sub or function when needed. Also Is there a place I can define it where the whole project sees it so I only have to define it once. If so I'll define them all in that location and always use the shorthand references.

```
Public Sub VTest()

Dim WbStats As Workbook
Dim WSPO1sts As Worksheet

Set WbStats = Worksbooks("Stats.xlsx") 'this line spawns the compile error I mentioned.
Set WSPO1sts = WbStats.Sheets("PO1sts")
```

Comment: typo? Worksbooks   should be Workbooks

Answer (score 0):

Note that if your code is in a workbook you can reference the workbook by using ActiveWorkbook

See [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/scope.aspx) which will explain more about declaring (ie define) variables and their scope.

[This site](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx) has a lot of information that you will find useful

eg
http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DeclaringVariables.aspx

Harvey